# filtering out dataset to eliminate one value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I only have four values in my dataset:

```
Value1
Value2
Value3
Value4
```

I want to filter my dataset so that it only has Value1, value2 and Value3. I don't want value4 in my dataset and then I want to bind my drop down list with this dataset. Here is what I have so far:

```
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds = SelectionProdCriteria.GetCostType()
        ds.Tables(0).DefaultView.RowFilter = "CostType=Value4" 
        ddlCostType.DataSource = ds
        ddlCostType.DataValueField = "CostType"
        ddlCostType.DataTextField = "CostType"
        ddlCostType.DataBind()
```

I am getting an error at   `ds.Tables(0).DefaultView.RowFilter = "CostType=Value4"`  saying Missing Operand after support operator.

I just want to see value1, value2 and Value3 in my drop down list and filter out value4.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq. Just get all element without Value4 like this:

```
Dim query = From ct In  ds.Tables(0).AsEnumerable() _
    Where ct.Field(Of String)("CostType") != Value4
    Select ct 
Dim view As DataView = query.AsDataView()
ddlCostType.DataSource = view
ddlCostType.DataValueField = "CostType"
ddlCostType.DataTextField = "CostType"
ddlCostType.DataBind()
```

Comment: what is order.AsEnumerable(). Its giving me an error saying Orders is not declared